# How to show a random image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to take a random picture of the wallpaper but it does not work.

this is my code:

```
<div id="img1" class="Square" style="background-image: url(img/01.jpg)" ></div>
```

---

```
<script>
    function displayDate() {
        var t1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
        document.getElementById("img1").style.backgroundImage= "url('t1.jpg')";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="img"+t1;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: when do you call to this function?

Comment: `"url('t1.jpg')"` <-- this is a static string, you are not calling the variable

Comment: please tell me how can i use t1 in url

Comment: Use `t1+ '.jpg'` as here: `document.getElementById("img1").style.backgroundImage= "url(t1 + '.jpg')";`

Comment: Also what are the names of your images (only numbers as `1.png` or `img1.png`)?

Comment: my images name is 1.jpg or 2.jpg

Comment: i have a even button and when i click on the Button i call my function

Comment: oh no; This code does not work

Comment: do your url path is correct?

Comment: yes and For example, when i use the code is working:
document.getElementById("img1").style.backgroundImage= "url( '1.jpg')"

Comment: sorry use as it:`document.getElementById("img1").style.backgroundImage= "url(" +t1 + ".jpg)";`

Comment: happy to help:) have a good day